# 15 x 15 polyomino

Tags: polyomino, packing

[image: 15 x 15 polyomino]

You cannot move the red squares

You cannot rotate the blocks

You cannot have 2 block of the same color touching each other, not even diagonally (by their corners)

Grey blocks cannot touch a red square, not even diagonally.

Blocks that have a red bit have to be placed so that their red bit comes over a red square.

Hint1: Place dark blue blocks exactly like that w.r.t. one another.

> [image: Hint 1]

Hint2: Place pink blocks exactly like that w.r.t. one another.

> [image: Hint2]

Hint3: Place yellow blocks exactly like that w.r.t. one another.

> [image: Hint3]

No credit to be given, I've just made it up (because I was amazed by how fast another polyomino had been solved).

Comment: Feel free to ask if you want another hint.

Comment: Even with the current hint, if there's no rough logical path to follow, I have a feeling this could be extremely difficult

Comment: Looks like the description has some issues: 1. red vs. orange.  2. The blue I tetromino is missing its red square.  3. Are there supposed to be five red squares among the polyominoes?

Comment: The dark blue pattern in the first hint has a red square which is not on the pieces figuring on the original drawing. It is just there to show where the dark blue pieces should be placed.

Comment: @Jaap Scherphuis I counted the squares on the pieces (not counting the 2 red ones). 39 light blue, 35 dark blue, 34 grey, 30 pink, 40 yellow and 42 light green. So it adds up to 220 as it should.

Comment: @RobPratt Not currently, but there could be. Would you like me to add 3 more? There's no red and orange, there's only red.

Comment: Sorry, I did indeed miscount. I accidentally made one of the pieces too long. I have deleted my previous comment.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Solution:

> [image]

---

Explanation:

> Using the hints we have the new starting position:
>
>  [image]
>
> From here we have only grey, green and cyan left and there's some obvious placements, particularly around the middle as the grey can't touch the red:
>
>  [image]
>
> Now we can place the majority of the cyan top right as it all has only one way it can fit. A few other gaps to the top and top left can also be filled.
>
>  [image]
>
> And finally the last few steps can only be filled one way:
>
>  [image]

(Note there's no way I could have done this without the starting hints)

Comment: Well done Beastly Gerbil :)